# How to get objects from an ArrayList inside a session using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

Using Spring I'm trying to obtain and print the attributes from the object "Auto". Under my controller I'm requested the data from a form... I create a new object "Auto" using that data.. then I add that created object into an ArrayList and finally pass the ArrayList to a session. However, when I try to obtain and print the data from the ArrayList I get nothing, a blank page.

Auto.class code:

```
package beans;


public class Auto {


private String codigo;
private String marca;
private String modelo;

public Auto() {
}


public Auto(String codigo, String marca, String modelo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
}

public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
}

public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}

public String getModelo() {
    return modelo;
}

public void setModelo(String modelo) {
    this.modelo = modelo;
}

@Override
public String toString() { 
return "codigo: '" + this.codigo + "', marca: '" + this.marca + "', modelo: '" + this.modelo + "'";
}


}
```

This is my controller code:

```
@Controller

public class procesarController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/procesar.htm" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addAuto(@RequestParam("codigo") String codigo,
       @RequestParam("marca") String marca,
       @RequestParam("modelo") String modelo,
       Model m,HttpSession s) 
{
  Auto a = new Auto(codigo,marca,modelo);
  ArrayList<Auto> autos = new ArrayList();
  autos.add(a);
  //m.addAttribute(autos);
  s.setAttribute("vehiculo", autos);     


  return "otro";
}


}
```

Here my jsp "otro" where I'm trying to print the ArrayList:

```
<h1>pagina de resultado</h1>


    <table border="1">

        <c:forEach var="a" items="${sessionScope.vehiculo}" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Codigo</td>
                <td>Marca</td>
                <td>Modelo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>${a.codigo}</td>
                <td>${a.marca}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Comment: items="${vehiculo}" inside your foreach in your jsp

Comment: in your Auto class,is there getter/setter for codigo,marca?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing this taglib at the top of my "otro.jsp"

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need varStatus="somename" in your forEach in your jsp like this:

```
<c:forEach var="a" items="${vehiculo}" varStatus="status" >
```

then you need to use this inside `<td>`:

```
${vehiculo[status.index].codigo}
```

Comment: It keeps giving me a blank table. Viewing the source code in items it says "[beans.Auto@6487f93f]"

Comment: i think you need to @override toString method in your POJO

Comment: Done it, now items show correctly the data when viewing the source code. However, the table keeps showing up empty.

Answer (score 0):

try adding value in model or request to access values using ${.....}
(before returning view)..

```
model.addAttribute("vehiculo", autos);
//or 
request.setAttribute("vehiculo", autos);
```

and then on page

```
<c:forEach var="a" items="${vehiculo}" varStatus="status" >  
<tr>
      <td>${a.codigo}</td>
      <td>${a.marca}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

see if your attributes use is more than just a request and you are confident enough that no other user going to change that value from session then only try to access values from session,

but for multiple login of same user there might be a case of overwriting same session attribute so you might not get session values as expected so add values in model or request and then access..

Comment: It made no difference, still empty table.

Comment: have you configured internal view resolver properly to submit the model..?

Comment: I have yes, and still nothing. I have tried printing the data from the list (without using the foreach) and it works. For example, in this way "${requestScope.vehiculo[0].codigo}"

Comment: requestScope used when you absoluetely want your object to come from the request, and not from the page, session or application scope. Inded, using ${vehiculo} will search for a name attribute in the page, then request, then session, then application.

Let's say that other code in the JSP set vehiculo attribute in page scope,But you want to access vehiculo in request: you're forced to use requestScope.
Let's say the session might have a vehiculo attribute. Not using requestScope.vehiculo would return the session-scoped name if the JSP forgot to set the name attribute in the request scope.